# Stored procedure slower than query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Let me start off by saying that I haven't worked too much with stored procedures, so the way I've gone about this might be all wrong, but I figured I would come here and try and find the answer to my current problem before blowing the whole thing up and starting over.

I have a stored procedure that simply runs a bunch of other queries I have put together. It consists of a bunch of `Insert`, `Update`, and `Delete` queries, and when I run this stored procedure, it takes 2 hours to complete.

When I run each query individually it takes a total of about 45 minutes.

Obviously there is a big time difference between running them individually and running them as a stored procedure, but being able to run a single stored procedure is much more convenient.

I've done some research and the most common answer is that the slow down is due to "parameter sniffing". The issue that I'm having with the parameter sniffing answer is that I don't have any parameters built into my stored procedure. As I mentioned earlier, I built out a bunch of queries, and simply pasted them into the stored procedure. This probably wasn't the best way to do it, but it made sense to me at the time.

My questions is, does the stored procedure run slower because I don't have parameters or is runner slower for other reasons? Furthermore, is there a way to speed things up under the current configuration I have?

Here is an example of my stored procedure with the first couple queries.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LDS_Step_2]
AS
------------------------------------------------------
--******* Text Import 2 Append ********
------------------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Text_Import_2]([Foundation_Account_Number], [Foundation_Account_Name], [Billing_Account_Number], [Billing_Account_Name], [Wireless_Number], [Market_Cycle_End_Date], [Item], [Day], [Date], [Time], [To_From], [Type], [KB_Msg_Min], [Rate_Pd], [Rate_Code], [Feature], [In_Out], [Intl_Tax], [Roaming_indicator], [Total_Charge])
        Select
            [Foundation Account Number], [Foundation Account Name],
            [Billing Account Number], [Billing Account Name], 
            [dbo].[Master_Wireless_Number].Wireless_ID,
            LEFT([Market Cycle End Date],2) + '/' + SUBSTRING([Market Cycle End Date],3,2) + '/20' + RIGHT([Market Cycle End Date],2)  as [Market Cycle End Date],
            [Item], [Day], 
            LEFT([Date],2) + '/' + SUBSTRING([Date],3,2) + '/20' + RIGHT([Date],2) as [Date],
            [Time], [To From], [Type], [KB Msg Min], [Rate Pd], [Rate Code],
            [Feature], [In Out], [Intl Tax], [Roaming indicator],
            [Total Charge]
        FROM
            [dbo].[Text_Import]
        INNER JOIN 
            [dbo].[Master_Wireless_Number] ON [dbo].[Master_Wireless_Number].Wireless_Number = [dbo].[Text_Import].[Wireless Number]

    ------------------------------------------------------
    --******* Voice Import 2 Append *********
    ------------------------------------------------------



INSERT INTO [dbo].[Voice_Import_2] (
[Foundation Account Number]
,[Foundation Account Name]
,[Billing Account Number]
,[Billing Account Name]
,[Wireless Number]
,[Market Cycle End Date]
,[Item]
,[Date]
,[Time]
,[Number Called]
,[Called To]
,[Minutes Charged]
,[Rate Pd]
,[Rate Code]
,[Feature]
,[Airtime Charge]
,[LD Add Charge]
,[Intl Tax]
,[Roaming indicator]
,[Total]
)

Select
[Foundation Account Number]
,[Foundation Account Name]
,[Billing Account Number]
,[Billing Account Name]
,Master_Wireless_Number.Wireless_ID
,LEFT([Market Cycle End Date],2) + '/' + SUBSTRING([Market Cycle End Date],3,2) + '/20' + RIGHT([Market Cycle End Date],2)  as [Market Cycle End Date]
,[Item]
,LEFT([Date],2) + '/' + SUBSTRING([Date],3,2) + '/20' + RIGHT([Date],2) as [Date]
,[Time]
,[Number Called]
,[Called To]
,[Minutes Charged]
,[Rate Pd]
,[Rate Code]
,[Feature]
,[Airtime Charge]
,[LD Add Charge]
,[Intl Tax]
,[Roaming indicator]
,[Total]
FROM [dbo].[Voice_Import]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Master_Wireless_Number] ON [dbo].[Master_Wireless_Number].Wireless_Number = [dbo].[Voice_Import].[Wireless Number]
```

Comment: User doesn't have any parameters in query

Comment: You may need to check for locking/blockings ,wait stats when the query is running if you are able to repro the issue every time.Here is a good place to start  :http://www.sqlsentry.com/white-papers/troubleshooting-sql-server-wait-stats

Comment: Look at query plans' differences within your SP and for SSMS queries

Comment: https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/category/diagnostic-queries/  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13748067/SQL%20Server%202016%20Diagnostic%20Information%20Queries%20%28June%202016%29.sql

Comment: Are you running the stored procedure inside a transaction? If so, then it could be slowness from the transaction log. There are various ways around it if that's the issue. In any case, diagnosing performance problems without query plans and a lot of other information is going to be pretty tough.

Comment: Do you have some indexes on your tables, both the sources and the targets ? Do you have clustered indexes ? Have you tried to separate your statement into several stored procedures, and call them with a SQL Job ?